# Getting the selected value of an auto generated select in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Well I have this in my html:

```
<div id="students"></div>
```

In my JavaScript file I add a select to this div. Like this:

```
$('<select class="browser-default custom-select" id="studentSelect">').appendTo($('#students'));

        data.forEach(x => {
            $('<option>')
                .html(x.name)
                .appendTo($('#students select'));
        })
```

My question now is how can I get the selected value of this select and print it to the console. This is my code so far:

```
var sel = $('#studentSelect');
console.log(sel.value);
```

Result: I'm getting undefined on the console.

Comment: For jQuery objects it's `.val()` not `.value` (which is vanilla JS)

Comment: Still getting undefined

Comment: That's why we always ask people to post a [mre]. It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1uqh92x5/

Answer (score 0):

The answer above from Chris G is correct. My guess is that you are firing the console.log before the select is created and populated or the problem is somewhere else, you need to provide more from your code to be able to help you better.

You can check here how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzapurm1/

```
var data = [{name: "Michael"}, {name: "John"}, {name: "Peter"}]; //My assumption of your data array
$('<select class="browser-default custom-select" id="studentSelect">').appendTo($('#students'));    
data.forEach(x => {
    $('<option>')
        .html(x.name)
        .appendTo($('#students select'));
});

var sel = $('#studentSelect');
console.log(sel.val());
```